# How to dynamically modifying a function without causing an infinite recursive call?

Tags: r

Let's say I have a function `f <- function(x) x + 2` and I want to modify it to return half the result it previously returned.

I tried `f <- function(x) f(x) / 2` which causes an infinite recursive call (predictable).

I've come up with a really dirty solution:

```
f <- eval(parse(text = sprintf("function(x) {%s / 2}", 
                               paste0(deparse(body(f)), collapse = ""))))
```

Has someone a more elegant solution?

Comment: Why not just rename the original and create a new one? `g = f; f = function(...) return(g(...) / 2)`

Comment: This function is in fact an attribute of an object (that I get and modify using `attr(obj, "f")`) so I can't just rename it.

Comment: This does not generalize at all beyond your example, but `body(f) <- as.call(list(as.symbol("/"), body(f), 2))`

Comment: Can you describe what output you need?

Comment: @Ouistiti The "dirty solution" at the end shows it.

Comment: @Frank This could work and this is nicer.

Comment: I think Gregor's point is still valid. Why not just `g<-attr(obj, 'f'); blah <- function(...) return(g(...)/2); attr(obj, 'f') <- blah`? Also, some more context would help, maybe there are alternative ways to your goal.

Comment: @dash2 If I want to clean up by deleting `g` afterwards, it breaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want something like this:

```
halvf <- function(f) {
    g <- f
    function(x) {
        g(x) / 2
    }
}
```

Then you can do the following:

```
x <- data.frame()
attr(x, "f") <- function(x) { x + 2 }
attr(x, "f")(2)
[1] 4
attr(x, "f") <- halvf(attr(x, "f"))
attr(x, "f")(2)
[1] 2
attr(x, "f") <- halvf(attr(x, "f"))
attr(x, "f")(2)
[1] 1
attr(x, "f") <- halvf(attr(x, "f"))
attr(x, "f")(2)
[1] 0.5
```

Comment: This seems to be the cleaner way to do it.

Comment: I don't know much about closures / environments, but maybe this could be messy insofar as it changes `f`'s enclosing environment. So if `attr(x, "f") <- local({ y = 10; function(x) { x + y }})` to start out with, then we can access `environment(attr(x, "f"))$y` but after the function is overwritten, this object is placed deeper down (I think).

Comment: Agreed, I was trying to solve the initial problem with infinite recursion. When it's about to modify the body of the existing function, your solution might be the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

In general, modifying a function's body is messy. However, in the case of a [composition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Composition.html), `g(f(...))`, it can be handled:

```
body(f) <- as.call(list(as.symbol("/"), body(f), 2))
f 

# function (x) 
# (x + 2)/2
```

---

As a (dangerous) function...

```
wrap <- function(f, g, ...){
    body(f) <<- as.call(list(as.symbol(g), body(f), ...))
}

f <- function(x) x + 2
wrap(f, "/", 2)
f
# function (x) 
# (x + 2)/2
```

Comment: Hum, I think this won't work if `f` is a primitive function such as `abs` (won't work with `f <- abs` but with `f <- function(x) abs(x)`)